# Convert an int to date with this mask : DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql

I have an int representing a datetime :

```
20201212
20210809
....
...
```

I want to cast it like this :

```
12/12/2020
09/08/2021
...
...
```

In a stored procedure.

How can I do that ?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Yuck!  Keep the ISO format date.  Or convert to a date format in your database.

Comment: Fix the schema and use an appropriate type -- some date/time type in this case, **not** an integer.

Comment: Use integer arithmetic to get date parts `select val / 10000 y, (val % 10000) / 100  m, val % 100 d`, construct what you want from the parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions.  In pseudo-code, this looks like:

```
select (substr(cast(dt_int as char(8)), 7, 2) || 
        substr(cast(dt_int as char(8)), 5, 2) || 
        substr(cast(dt_int as char(8)), 1, 4)
       )
```

The exact functions depend on the database you are using.  You can also convert to a date and format that, but that syntax is even more database-dependent.